# Ambiguous Probablity question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Family has two children and it is known that at least one is girl. What is Probability that both are girls given that at least one is girl?

Comment: @Matti P.   So what could be the answer 1/2 or 1/3

Comment: It depends _how we found out_ that one child is a girl. The problem really is fundamentally ambiguous this way. You have to make additional assumptions to get a numeric answer, and the answer depends on which assumptions you make.

Comment: @DavidK can you elaborate which assumptions we need to make?

Comment: Suppose you asked a truthful person who knows all about the family, "Is at least one of the children a girl?" Suppose they say yes, and suppose that's the only thing you've ever found out about the sexes of the children. Then the answer is $\frac13.$ But if that did not happen, but instead you met a girl and she said she is one of the two children of that family, you now know that _at least one of the children is a girl,_ and the answer to the question is $\frac12.$ For further explanation, read the answers to "already has an answer" question.